# DropdowMenu does not show the selected Item

Tags: flutter

In the following code i can add and remove Tabs to the screen. For removing, i have defide a Button on the AppBar that after pressing it a DropdownMenu appears who let me select which Tab i want to remove and it removes the selected Item.
The problem that i have is that when i select a item DropdownMenu it does not show the selected item.

Thanks in advance for some help.

Follows the complete code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String? selectedTab = tabs[0].text;
  var tabName = "";

  static List<Tab> tabs = [
    const Tab(text: ""),
  ];

  List<Widget> tabViewChildren = [
    Container(
      height: 400,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        initialIndex: 0,
        length: tabs.length,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              actions: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: const Text("Enter tab name"),
                          content: TextField(
                            onChanged: (String value) {
                              tabName = value;
                            },
                          ),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            ElevatedButton(
                              child: const Text("Add"),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  tabs.add(Tab(text: tabName));
                                  tabViewChildren.add(Container(height: 400));
                                });
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.add_box,
                  ),
                  label: const Text('Add Tab'),
                ),
                Opacity(
                  opacity: tabs.isNotEmpty ? 1 : 0.4,
                  child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: const Text("Select tab to remove"),
                            content: tabs.isNotEmpty
                                ? DropdownButton<String>(
                                    items: tabs
                                        .map((tab) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                              value: tab.text,
                                              child: Text(tab.text ?? ""),
                                            ))
                                        .toList(),
                                    onChanged: (String? value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        selectedTab = value;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    value: selectedTab,
                                  )
                                : Container(),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              ElevatedButton(
                                child: const Text("Remove"),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    int index = tabs.indexWhere((tab) => tab.text == selectedTab);
                                    tabs.removeAt(index);
                                    tabViewChildren.removeAt(index);
                                    selectedTab = tabs.isNotEmpty ? tabs[0].text : null;
                                  });
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                    label: const Text('Remove Tab'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              title: const Text("Tab in Flutter"),
              bottom: TabBar(tabs: tabs),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(children: tabViewChildren)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem:
Flutter works as a tree, each node has its own build context so showDialog is returning a build with a new build context, therefore in your code whenever you call setState in the dialog => you are calling the setState for the parent context (page), basically, you are updating the Screen widget not the dialog widget.

The Solution:
you have to use StatefulBuilder inside the Dialog widget so that it will have its own setState functionality. see the code below

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String? selectedTab = tabs[0].text;
  var tabName = "";

  static List<Tab> tabs = [
    const Tab(text: ""),
  ];

  List<Widget> tabViewChildren = [
    Container(
      height: 400,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        initialIndex: 0,
        length: tabs.length,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              actions: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: const Text("Enter tab name"),
                          content: TextField(
                            onChanged: (String value) {
                              tabName = value;
                            },
                          ),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            ElevatedButton(
                              child: const Text("Add"),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  tabs.add(Tab(text: tabName));
                                  tabViewChildren.add(Container(height: 400));
                                });
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.add_box,
                  ),
                  label: const Text('Add Tab'),
                ),
                Opacity(
                  opacity: tabs.isNotEmpty ? 1 : 0.4,
                  child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return StatefulBuilder(
                            builder: (context, setState) => AlertDialog(
                              title: const Text("Select tab to remove"),
                              content: tabs.isNotEmpty
                                  ? DropdownButton<String>(
                                      items: tabs
                                          .map(
                                              (tab) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                                    value: tab.text,
                                                    child: Text(tab.text ?? ""),
                                                  ))
                                          .toList(),
                                      onChanged: (String? value) {
                                        selectedTab = value;
                                        setState(() {});
                                      },
                                      value: selectedTab,
                                    )
                                  : Container(),
                              actions: <Widget>[
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  child: const Text("Remove"),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      int index = tabs.indexWhere(
                                          (tab) => tab.text == selectedTab);
                                      tabs.removeAt(index);
                                      tabViewChildren.removeAt(index);
                                      selectedTab =
                                          tabs.isNotEmpty ? tabs[0].text : null;
                                    });
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                    label: const Text('Remove Tab'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              title: const Text("Tab in Flutter"),
              bottom: TabBar(tabs: tabs),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(children: tabViewChildren)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. As you suggested it display the selected and removes the item selected in the DropDownMenu. Only the actual Tab does not disappeared. It continuous be displayed.

Comment: you are welcome, for me, it was working fine on ios, the logic is correct. i suggest learning about state management techniques or you can use value notifer